# SLSB EJB 3.1 references in weblgioc

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb, weblogic12c

I have implement simple EJB 3.0 deployed it on weblogic 12c. The EJB contains a reference to a different EJB as a member declared as a reference of implemented local interface  with annotation @EJB. When I invoke a method of the encapsulated EJB I get a null pointer exception. The same does not happen when I inject session context or data source using @SessionContext or @Resource respectivley. What I want to understand is do I have to define a reference in  
  in weblogic.xml for linking two EJBs. Is this same for all production grade application servers like jboss, websphere or Tomcat EE.

Here is more details about code & deployment:

```
 @Remote
 public interface MyEjbRemote1 {
  abstract public void func1();    
}
 @Stateless 
public class MyEJB1 implements  MyEjbRemote1 {
 public void func1() {}
}
@Remote
public interface MyEjbRemote {
abstract public void func();
}

@Stateless
public class MyEjb implements MyEjbRemote, MyEjbLocal {
@EJB
MyEjbRemote1 ejb1;
@Resource
SessionContext sessionContext;
public void func() {    
    ejb1.func1();
}
public void func1() {
    System.out.println("Local interface call for EJB");
}
}
```

The call to func1 method using remote interface is throwing a null pointer exception.

I have not put any details in ejb-jar.xml, weblogic-ejb-jar.xml or weblogic.xml. My question is what addition details is required.

Comment: you need to post your deployment structure and explain what you try to access from where

Comment: @highstakes I have edited and added my code

Comment: deployment structure = your EAR or WAR structural setup. You are possibly incorrectly accessing MyEjb where it's used from the web tier. Or you just did not define your ejb module in application.xml. Look at the log files or the admin console to see if your ejbs are actually recognized properly and theres no deployment exceptions.

Comment: @highstakes there is no web tier here just accessing the EJB from SE client which is valid in EE terms. Based on my readup on various resources available online. The DI in EJB 3.0 automatically injects a reference to a bean based on interface type it automatically looks up the JNDI tree. What am I getting wrong

Comment: Try adding a local interface to it since you are accessing it locally. Other than that if you are doing the JNDI lookup correctly from the client, and your deployment is a JAR EJB I don't know whats the problem.